# How to use a sigmoid function in multi-layer perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, perceptron

If I need to classify the object that is given to the neural network, and there are 4 classes that can be chosen from, how does it work with a sigmoid function?

Should I have 4 neurons in the hidden layer each of which should correspond to each class? Like if the 1st neuron gives the biggest output, say 0.8, then it's the first class?

Or should I have a neuron in an output layer, that will take outputs of hidden layer as inputs, pass them to the activation function and then classify the output like:

```
if (output < 0.25) return class1;
...
if (output <= 1) return class4;
```

Please help, I've been searching for a really long time now and I have read a lot of articles and some chapters in books but it's never brought up, it drives me crazy at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### One-hot encoding

The classic approach would use a one-hot encoding for that last layer, i.e., if an item belongs to the 3rd class out of four possible, then you'd encode it as the vector [0 0 1 0], so your output layer would have four neurons.

For training, you might want to normalize the output so that it sums up to 1 - i.e., if it manages to return [1 2 1 0] then you'd treat it as [0.5 1 0.5 0].

This all refers to the actual final layer - the size of hidden layer(s) is pretty much arbitrary (and likely much larger than your output layer), and the "meaning" of particular neurons within it isn't prescribed, it's learned from data.

Comment: oh, it turns out to be so obvious. Now I see how to use it. Thank you a lot, dude!